# How to unmap 'nmap <silent><buffer>' mapping

Tags: vim

This is a question about how to unmap a keybinding.  In general, unmapping keybindings is not hard, but I am having difficulty in this case.  I have tried to find relevant information in `:help`, but the keybinding is a bit complex--I still don't understand it--and I am not able to unmap it from inside a config file like .vimrc.

The `merlin' package for editing OCaml source code provides a set of configuration files for vim.  There is one definition I don't want:

```
nmap <silent><buffer> gd  :MerlinLocate<return>
```

I would rather not comment it out in the autoloaded `merlin.vim` file, because this file will repeatedly be automatically generated when I set up a new OCaml configuration.  Instead, I simply want to override this definition by unmapping `gd` in my own configuration file.

If I execute

```
nunmap <silent><buffer> gd
```

by hand at the `:` prompt while editing an OCaml file, `gd` is unmapped, as I want.  (I don't understand with `<silent><buffer>` means, but it seems to be necessary to unmap the key binding.)

However, if I place the same line in .vimrc (or in a file that I run with `-u`), `gd` is not unmapped.  (Changing `nunmap` to `unmap` does the same thing--works at the `:` prompt, not in the startup file.)

How can I unmap `gd`?

(Is the problem that these keys are not mapped when the `nunmap` command is executed, because at that point there's no OCaml source file in the current buffer?  There's some workaround for that, I'm sure, though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<buffer>` in `nmap <silent><buffer> gd :MerlinLocate<return>` means that this mapping is buffer-local.

Since it is defined for each `ocaml` buffer each time the `FileType` event is triggered with the value `ocaml` you will have a hard time overriding it globally.

What should work, though, is overriding that mapping in your own `ocaml` ftplugin:

```
" in after/ftplugin/ocaml.vim
nunmap <buffer> gd
```

But this is all a moot point since that mapping could be disabled [via a simple global variable](https://github.com/ocaml/merlin/blob/master/vim/merlin/doc/merlin.txt#L280).

Comment: Thanks romainl.  I assumed that you meant to add `nunmap <buffer> gd` to a new file .vim/after/ftplugin/ocaml.vim (which is a nice idea--I wasn't aware of this trick).  However, when I do that I'm getting "E31: No such mapping" on the `nunmap` line in that file.  Hmm.  I wonder if the reason this fails is because of how the OCaml setup loads the merlin file.  It's not placed under .vim.  I'll work on that idea. (Re "But this is all a moot point since that mapping could be disabled via a simple global variable": Yes, but I want the other default keybindings.)

Comment: `:scriptnames` shows that .vim/after/ftplugin/ocaml.vim is run after ocaml.vim under the main MacVim.app directory, but before the merlin config script in  ~/.opam/4.06.1/share/merlin/vim/autoload/merlin.vim .  So I need to figure out how to run a script after that file runs.

Comment: Or maybe I should give up and comment out the `gd` definition in  ~/.opam/4.06.1/share/merlin/vim/autoload/merlin.vim, and then fix it again every time I have a new version of that file.

Comment: Yes, the mapping is defined in a function which makes it a bit hard to unmap. That is bad design IMO. I guess you will have to edit it in the plugin itself.